# dynamically load images from server in jtinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using jtinder for creating tinder like effect. here is the library.

```
  https://github.com/do-web/jTinder
```

i want to add images dynamically when users are on 4th image out of 5 images loaded when page was called first time.

here is the javascript someone used to make dynamic call but i am not getting how to call  data from server as pattern and name of all images will be different everytime.

```
      $.fn[ pluginName ] = function (options) {
    this.each(function () {

        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
        else {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName).bindNew(this);
        } 

    });

    return this;
};
```

any help to make jquery/ajax call to server after 4th image is swiped will be great help

Comment: Do you still need help with this, because I just kinda solved this today morning...

Comment: @Xzhibit yes plz share

Answer (score 0):

Add a destroy method to the plugin prototype in jTinder.js:

```
destroy: function(element){
    $(element).unbind();
    $(this.element).removeData();
}
```

like so:

```
     init: function (element) {

        container = $(">ul", element);
        panes = $(">ul>li", element);
        pane_width = container.width();
        pane_count = panes.length;
        current_pane = panes.length - 1;
        $that = this;

        $(element).bind('touchstart mousedown', this.handler);
        $(element).bind('touchmove mousemove', this.handler);
        $(element).bind('touchend mouseup', this.handler);
    },

    destroy: function(element){
        $(element).unbind();
        $(this.element).removeData();
    }

    showPane: function (index) {
        panes.eq(current_pane).hide();
        current_pane = index;
    },
```

And then create a function, addcard() where you first fetch the data you want from a JSON source, add it to the main  under the tinderslide, delete and then reinitialize the jTinder event.

```
function addcard(){
    $.getJSON("example.json",function(data){
        //assign the data
        var elem="<li>"+data+"</li>";
        //delete existing jTinder event
        $("#tinderslide").data('plugin_jTinder').destroy();
        //reinitialize new jTinder event
        $("#tinderslide").jTinder({
            onDislike:function(){
                doSomething();
            }
            onLike:function(){
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And call `addcard()` whenever you need to add a new card.